# Multiple WordPress on Virtual Host

Tags: multisite, virtual-hosts

I have AWS EC2 Linux server. Currently only one wordpress multisite mode is hosted in root folder (/var/www/html).

Now I would like to host another wordpress site. So that I have enable apache virtual host.

Here is my vhost.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName firstdomain.com
ServerAlias www.firstdomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName seconddomain.com
ServerAlias www.seconddomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/seconddomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I have one php test file inside seconddomain.com folder and I can browse by www.seconddomain.com

After that I download wordpress and copy into seconddomain.com folder and change the wp-config.php.

But I got the error "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Is it because I have one wordpress in root folder or other security reason?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Have you tried putting the first domain in a subdirectory?

Comment: Hi, not yet. It is running website and I am afraid It might lost some URL. I need time to move word press from root folder to sub folder. Do you have any recommended article. thanks for reply.

Comment: Codex is a good bible: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comments.

I can manage to host two separate WordPress site on VirtualHost EC2 Linux AMI.

My mistake is I have created the vhost.conf file in under /etc/httpd/conf.d.

Correct way to enable VirtualHost on EC2 Linux AMI is as follow :

1. go to /etc/httpd/conf
2. open httpd.conf file
3. go to end of file
4. uncomment NameVirtualHost *:80 line
5. add the virtual host

Thanks,
Alex